# Google Analytics on Kartra

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Google analytics doesn't seem to send through accurate data from my Kartra website. I know it's successfully embedded but something doesn't seem right based on knowing who visited my site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have visitors from Australia and the UK for sure. Analytics shows that I've only 8 visitors from Germany in a week. Totally inaccurate, doesn't make sense